# Can't assign proper value to QCombBox using PySide

Tags: python, pyside

Since Pyside can't be pickled, I've decided to manually write all my system parameters to a file that, when opened via QFileDialog, can be used to populate all the QWidgets with the appropriate data...so far, everything works except for one of the QWidgets, `dataBox`, which is a QComboBox in a separate class.

As you'll see in the following code, I put print lines to see the values of a list that stores parameters. In the stdout, you can see that all the values are as they should be, but the `QComboBox.setEditText()` method doesn't assign the value properly so that the combo box displays the text that is set to it...the images I linked show two things about the "openFile" case: the text displayed in the QComboBox (`dataBox`) is positioned strangely (it works, but should be centered), and the two separate instances of `FigureCanvas` that display the data are showing the same data (since the boxes are being assigned the same value which is also the first value in the `dictionary/QComboBox`). These two instances of `dataBox` should have DA_0 & DA_1 in them, but they both have DA_0.

I tried a different method of the `QComboBox` class, `setItemText()`, but that didn't even display any data or populate the dataBox.

Here are links to screenshots of the GUI in both the [saveFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvK6y.jpg) case and the [openFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyvxK.jpg) case.

Here's the relevant code & the [full code](https://gist.github.com/Aweeeezy/f029a7361247e242b03e). I apologize for the formatting in the gist...copying from a TextEdit didn't work so will.

This method, `openFile`, properly pulls the appropriate data from the file, but the setEditText() method doesn't properly set the `dataBox` to show it. Do be perfectly clear, the value `DA_1` prints properly right before it is added to the combo box, but once it's added to the combo box, something goes wrong...these are the two most important lines of code to observe:

`print "dataBox value ", self.graphValues[x]              # works fine`
`self.opts[opt].dataBox.setEditText(self.graphValues[x])  # doesn't work at all`

`self.opts` is a dictionary of strings (names of figures/plots) paired with instances of a class that handles setting the graphing options

dataBox is the QComboBox that holds all the strings (names of figures/plots)

```
# Read parameters from file and sets sim/graphValues (1.1)
def openFile(self):
    self.filePath, _= QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'open file', \
        '~/', 'C Files (*.c);;Simulations (*.sim)' )
    fullPath = self.filePath.split("/")
    title = fullPath[-1]
    self.w.setWindowTitle(title)
    if self.filePath[-4:] == ".sim":
        with open(self.filePath, 'r') as f:
            self.simValues = [""]
            value = f.readline()
            while 1:
                if value != "\n":
                    self.simValues.append(value)
                    value = f.readline()
                else: break
            self.graphValues = [""]
            value = f.readline()
            while 1:
                if value != "\n":
                    self.graphValues.append(value)
                    value = f.readline()
                else: break
            self.files = f.readlines()
        self.numSim.setText(self.simValues[1])
        self.numTrials.setText(self.simValues[2])
        self.numTicks.setText(self.simValues[3])
        self.numGraphs.setText(self.simValues[4])
        self.dirPath = self.simValues[5]
        x = 1
        for opt in self.opts:
            self.opts[opt].styleSelect.setEditText(str(self.styles[opt]))
            self.opts[opt].dataBox.addItems(self.files)
            if self.opts[opt].styleSelect.currentText() == "1":
                print "dataBox value ", self.graphValues[x]
                self.opts[opt].dataBox.setEditText(self.graphValues[x]);x+=1
                print "xlabel value ", self.graphValues[x]
                self.opts[opt].xLabel.setText(self.graphValues[x]);x+=1
                print "ylabel value ", self.graphValues[x]
                self.opts[opt].yLabel.setText(self.graphValues[x]);x+=1
                print "xrange value ", self.graphValues[x]
                self.opts[opt].xRange.setText(self.graphValues[x]);x+=1
                print "yrange value ", self.graphValues[x]
                self.opts[opt].yRange.setText(self.graphValues[x]);x+=1
            elif self.opts[opt].styleSelect.currentText() == "2":
                pass
            else:
                pass
        self.plot()
```

This method, saveFile, is not really necessary to show, but I wanted to be clear that the issue is NOT with writting the data.

```
# Saves sim & graph values and writes them to file (1.2)
def saveFile(self):
    self.filePath, _= QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'save file', \
         '~/', 'Simulations (*.sim)' )
    fullPath = self.filePath.split("/")
    title = fullPath[-1]
    self.w.setWindowTitle(title)
    self.simValues = [str(self.numSim.text()),str(self.numTrials.text()), \
                      str(self.numTicks.text()),str(self.numGraphs.text())]
    self.simValues.append(self.dirPath)
    self.graphValues = []
    for opt in self.opts:
        self.styles[opt] = self.opts[opt].styleSelect.currentText()
        if self.opts[opt].styleSelect.currentText() == "1":
            self.graphValues.append(self.opts[opt].dataBox.currentText())
            self.graphValues.append(self.opts[opt].xLabel.text())
            self.graphValues.append(self.opts[opt].yLabel.text())
            self.graphValues.append(self.opts[opt].xRange.text())
            self.graphValues.append(self.opts[opt].yRange.text())
        elif self.opts[opt].styleSelect.currentText() == "2":
            pass
        else:
            pass
    with open(self.filePath, 'w') as f:
        for item in self.simValues:
            f.write(item+"\n")
        f.write("\n")
        for item in self.graphValues:
            f.write(item+"\n")
        f.write("\n")
        for item in self.files:
            f.write(item+"\n")
```

Here are the stdout print lines:

```
dataBox value  DA_1

xlabel value  other

ylabel value  things

xrange value  len(data)

yrange value  y range

dataBox value  DA_0

xlabel value  some

ylabel value  stuff

xrange value  len(data)

yrange value  y range
```

Comment: What do you mean by "assign the value properly"? `setEditText` changes the text in the text edit of the combo box. Do you want to do that?

Comment: By "assign the value properly", I mean change the text in the combo box. The bottom print lines of my original post show that the dataBox value that should be assigned to Fig2 is `DA_1` and the dataBox value that should be assigned to Fig 1 is `DA_0`...yet, the line immediately following those print lines is the one that actually performs the QComboBox.setEditText() and it does not set the combo box text areas to the values that the previous print line indicates.